# How to configure Backuppc in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: backup, backuppc

I would like to setup Backuppc to Backup files of all remote hosts. A need guide with screenshots will be appreciated.

#### Details:

- All the hosts are running ubuntu, i need to set incremental backup for the files which is kept in their desktop.
- Need to monitor backup status from server using web GUI.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupPC)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Outline

1. Installation
2. BackupPC web user
3. Client Connection Preparation - Setup SSH-KEY
4. Configure BackupPC to backup Client's /home directory
5. Adding Client
6. Backup Schedule

### 1. Installation

Install via Ubuntu BackupPC package

```
    sudo apt-get install backuppc
```

This will install BackupPC and configure the following automatically

```
    Linux User   : backuppc (home directory /var/lib/backuppc)
                   BackupPC daemon will run as this user

    HTTP User    : backuppc (For web gui http login)
                   Password is located in /etc/backuppc/htpasswd (See Step 2)

    Config file location : /etc/backupc
    Data file location   : /var/lib/backuppc

    Apache will be configured
    Web Interface URL    : http://<hostname/IP>/backuppc
```

**This guide is base on the above installation method and information.**

If manual installation is used, in `config.pl`, look for following line

```
    set $Conf{CgiAdminUsers}     = '';
```

and change to

```
    set $Conf{CgiAdminUsers}     = 'backuppc';
```

### 2. BackupPC web user

**HTTP Login/User backuppc**

To have full administrative right in BackupPC web interface, one have to login as `backuppc` and password. (This is **not** the same as the linux user.)

The web interface user(http login) `backuppc` is created with a random password during installation. If you forget to write down the password, use `htpasswd` to change it as follow

```
    sudo htpasswd /etc/backuppc/htpasswd backuppc
```

**Additional User**

To add additional user

```
    sudo htpasswd /etc/backuppc/htpasswd <username>
```

In **Step 5 Add Client**, put < username > into `moreUsers` field. When < username > login web interface, will only see client they are assigned to.

### 3. Client Connection Preparation - Setup SSH-KEY

**Client SSHD Configuration**

To keep it simple, client machines sshd should allow root login. For each client `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, make sure following options are there and un-commented

```
    PermitRootLogin yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This should be done on all clients to speed up the next step, as `scp` will be used.

**Server SSH KEY Creation and Deployment**

1. On server, login as user `backuppc`

   ```
   backuppc@server$ sudo su - backuppc
   ```
2. Generate SSH Key Pair with Empty Pass Phase

   ```
   backuppc@server$ ssh-keygen
   ```

   When asked for phasephase, leave it empty(press <kbd>enter</kbd>)

   ```
   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
   Enter same passphrase again:
   ```

   That will generate 2 files in /var/lib/backuppc/.ssh: `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. You only need to generate one pair of key.
3. Deploy Key To Client Machine

   Copy `id_rsa.pub` to client machine

   ```
   backuppc@server$ scp /var/lib/backuppc/.ssh/id_rsa.pub sudo-user@<client machine>:/home/sudo-user/backuppc.id_ras.pub
   backuppc@server$ ssh sudo-user@<client machine>

   sudo-user@client$ chmod 600 backuppc.id_ras.pub
   sudo-user@client$ sudo mkdir /root/.ssh
   sudo-user@client$ sudo chmod 700 /root/.ssh
   sudo-user@client$ sudo mv backuppc.id_ras.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
   sudo-user@client$ sudo chown root:root /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

   Test ssh connection(On server, as Linux user backuppc)

   ```
   backuppc@server$ ssh root@<client machine>
   ```

   It should not ask for password.

   **It is important to do the test because this will also add client machine fingerprint to backuppc(linux user) .ssh/known_hosts list. Otherwise when BackupPC(the software) connect(via ssh) to client machine, it will be prompt for fingerprint confirmation, which it cannot handle, and the backup process will fail.**

   Repeat step 3 for all client machines.

   At this point, server user `backuppc` should be able to ssh into all client machines as root, **without being prompt for password nor fingerprint confirmation nor passphase**.

### 4. Configure BackupPC to backup Client's /home directory

1. Open BackupPC web GUI
2. On left panel, **Server** section, click **Edit Config**
3. On right panel, click **Xfer** tab
4. In **Xfer** tab, change following, then click **Save** on top

   ```
   XferMethod: rsync
   RsyncShareName: /home
   ```

   (Assume only backing up user home directories)
5. This will automatically apply to all clients.

   [image: Screen Shot]

### 5. Adding Client

1. Open BackupPC web GUI
2. On left panel, `Server` section, click `Edit Hosts`
3. For each machine, fill in hostname or IP address under `host`, and always use `backuppc` for `user`, click `Add` for more rows. Remember to click `Save` on top when finish.
4. Delete localhost from the list

   [image: Screen Shot]

   The situation become tricky if dhcp is used for desktop machines. There are a few ways to work around this

   1. configure dhcpd to assign static IP to them
   2. change desktop machines to use static IPs
   3. configure dynamic dns update

   **In any case, server need to be able to reach(ssh) each client machine consistently either with an IP address or a hostname.**

### 6. Backup Schedule

1. Open BackupPC web GUI
2. On left panel, **Server** section, click **Edit Config**
3. On right panel, click **Schedule** tab
4. Nothing to be done, the default schedule will perform

   ```
   Full Backup every 7 days (FullPeriod: 6.97 day)
   Incremental Backup everyday (IncrPeriod: 0.97 day)
   ```

   [image: Screen Shot]

### 7. Adding Audit Interface

[Adding an Audit Interface to BackupPC](http://www.tummy.com/blogs/2009/03/05/adding-an-audit-interface-to-backuppc/) has instruction to add an audit only interface to BackupPC.

However the index.cgi in Ubuntu BackupPC package is compiled. `/usr/share/backuppc/lib/realindex.cgi` should be used to generate `audit.cgi` mentioned in the blog.

Comment: Is `backup failed (Unable to read 4 bytes)` still happening?

Comment: @karthick87 I updated Step 2 for adding additional users.

Comment: @karthick87 Server->Edit Config -> CGI(Tab), go to bottom section 'User Config Editing' and remove check mark for option you do not want other user to have.

Comment: @karthick87 You can remove the configuration edit right, but the  user will always able to start/stop/browse/restore backups they are assigned to. If you want to only allow them to view backup status, you have to create a separate web page and pull BackupPC status in background.

Comment: I will have to look into that later tonight as I kind of remeber the index.cgi seems to be compiled in ubuntu package.

Comment: @karthick87 Answer updated with audit interface info.

Comment: @karthick87 Are you using LVM?

Comment: Yes we are using LVM..

Comment: @karthick87 (Method 1) The easiest way is to add your new drive to LVM and expend the LVM volume. (Method 2) Replace the old small drive with the new big one. Use `dd` to copy the old drive to the new drive. Then resize LVM and partition accordingly.

Comment: It feel strange to find myself searching for my own answer after 6 years ...

Answer (score 1):

You could mount a folder of your backupPC on the remote PCs and use the default backup tool of Ubuntu to store the backup on this mounted share.

Or if you're familiar with bash scripting you could write a script using rsync to copy the files on the backupPC and let the script run on a regular basis via cron jobs.

If you google for "mount network share" I think you can find a screenshoted guide.

Something I found by googling is this pictured guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/SimpleBackupSuite that uses SimpleBackupSuite. Never tried that one.

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: The idea of BackupPC is, as far as I know, that it avoids the need to mount file systems remotely. And the OP isn't asking for an alternative. :)