# Ubuntu Server 12.04 on Dell PowerEdge T320

Tags: 12.04, server, dell, backuppc

Is it possible to install/run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server with BackupPC backup software correctly on Dell PowerEdge T320 server (Xeon E5-2403 1.80GHz/10MB / 1x4GB Dual Rank RDIMM 1600MHz) with PERC H310 RAID controller? We are thinking of changing our old backup server and need to be sure that this will really work prior to ordering.

Comment: For me, Dell Precision T3600, with PREC H310. Ubuntu 12.04 Server doesn't boot on live USB key.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu offers a [certified hardware database](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/).

Doing a simple search I found [**Dell PowerEdge T310**](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201011-6781/) and [**Dell  PowerEdge T410**](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201011-6780/). They both work flawlessly. Also [**Dell PERC H310**](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/scsi:1000B:111BF-DISK/) works.

Answer (score 1):

The T320 has now been certified on Ubuntu 12.04.1 with the H310 Controller:

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201210-12063/

Backuppc should not have any issues running on this hardware with 12.04:

[How to configure Backuppc in ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191991/how-to-configure-backuppc-in-ubuntu-12-04)